# mobicents can make a call but doesint show in server

Tags: sip

hi following a tut at https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/Mobicents-SipServlets-Release/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/documentation/html_single/index.html#getting-started-with-MSS-Tomcat-AS7 i can make a call between 2 sofphones which both say they have registered but in mobicents click2call server page no information is displayed and it states "No registered users. Please register at least two SIP User Agents." which couldint be the case if i can make and take calls anyone have any idea why this would happen.

Answer (score 1):

By default Mobicents SIP Servlets uses the following application by default https://code.google.com/p/sipservlets/wiki/HTML5WebRTCVideoApplication

If you want to change the default application, go to the Mobicents SIP Servlets management console `http://127.0.0.1:8080/sip-servlets-management` and change the application routing so the default application that receives the INVITE and REGISTER. More on default application routing (DAR) management at [https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/Mobicents-SipServlets-Release/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/documentation/html_single/index.html#sssicar-SIP_Servlets_Server-Application-Router](https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/Mobicents-SipServlets-Release/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/documentation/html%5fsingle/index.html#sssicar-SIP%5fServlets%5fServer-Application-Router)